# How can I work with Portaudio in WSL in windows 10?

Tags: sound, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am working on WSL(Ubuntu) in windows 10, I need to use portaudio in my project.
I did the following:

- I downloaded `pa_stable_v190600_20161030.tgz` from [portaudio site](http://www.portaudio.com/download.html) into my computer
- Using Ubuntu terminal I ran .`/configure` and then ran `make` :

  [image: image1]

  [image: image2]

When I went into `bin` and ran the `./pa_devs`, I am getting 0 device.

I doubt that there is an issue with working with audio in WSL.
I want to know, how I can overcome this problem.

Comment: wsl does not support audio

Comment: Thats True @AlvinLiang but is it possible to enable audio like given in https://token2shell.com/howto/x410/enabling-sound-in-wsl-ubuntu-let-it-sing/

Comment: WSL does not support audio, and there are indeed ways of making it work, but those are *Windows* solutions, which are off-topic here, but on-topic on our sister site https://superuser.com.